# Identify defendant in small claims court (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, subpoena

If I want to make a claim against someone in small claims court in the UK, but I only have their PO Box address, what's the procedure? I need some legal thing to compel Royal Mail to give me their identity but I can't even figure out the name of it (I guess subpoena in the US?).

Comment: Not very helpful for me but if anyone from google is looking for this information in the US apparently you can use a [request for boxholder information](https://klemalaw.com/blog/2021/11/01/get-someones-name-and-address-based-on-a-po-box-only-or-find-out-where-a-person-moved-to/).